# There is a problem with the result of my function #readability test in CS50

Tags: c, cs50

So I have written this code and I get the result of letters,words,sentences of a text and I use a formula that calculates the grade of this text
`index = 0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8`

but for some reason when I try a text for example :

```
There are more things in Heaven and Earth, Horatio, than are dreamt of in your philosophy.
```

(The grade should be 9 based on the result in CS50 paper)
But i get wrong results like 10 for this example.
I did the calculations in google to see if I do something wrong but it shows me 10 there too.
[image]

The code is here:

```c
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    int sentences = 0;
    int letters =0;
    int words = 0;
    string text = get_string("Text: ");

    int n = strlen(text);
    for(int i = 0; i<n ; i++){
        if((text[i]== '.' || text[i]== '?' || text[i]== '!') ){
            sentences += 1;
        } else if (text[i]== 32){
            words += 1;
        }else if (isalpha(text[i]))
        {
            letters += 1;
        }

    }

    float L = ((float)letters / (float)words) *100.00;
    float S = ((float)sentences / (float)words) *100.00;
    int index = round(0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8);
    printf("%i\n",letters);
    printf("%i\n",words);
    printf("%i\n",sentences);

    if(index<1)
    {
        printf("Before Grade 1");
    }
    else if (index>16)
    {
        printf("Grade 16+");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("(Grade %i)\n",index);
    }

}
```

Comment: Which paper is that?

Comment: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/psets/2/readability/ @zakk at the end i have to test these texts on my programm

Comment: Did you verify each of your counters? If you find a `.` that also terminates a word, doesn't it?

Comment: @Gerhardh yes its in the if statement . '.' doesnt terminates the word, only when it finds 'space'=32 in ascii

Comment: For easier debugging you could add the text as string literal into your code instead of asking for input again and again.

Comment: @nickglav No, it isn't. You are not counting a word after full stops.

Comment: Which if statement? There are 3 of them. I don't see one that increments the word counter in case of a `.`. (Of course `.` followed by `' '` should not be counted twice)

Comment: @Gerhardh did you find where the problem may be?

Comment: I think, not counting the last word might be one issue.

Comment: it shouldnt be incremented if it find '.'

Comment: So, you switched from "it is done" to "it should not"... But what about `"Eat this!"` How many words are that for you?

Comment: @Zakk it doesnt seem to be the problem "."

Comment: @Gerhardh 7 letters,1 word,1 sentence

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246053/discussion-between-gerhardh-and-nick-glav).

Answer (score 1):

So the answer is to add a starting point of 1 to words because i doesnt calculates the end word!
int words = 1;

thanks @Gerhardh and @Zakk